# Expected expression error in keil uvision (Tiva C Arm/ TM4C123GH6PM)

Tags: embedded, keil, pwm

```
void PortF_Init(void){
    SYSCTL_RCGC2_R |=(1<<5);
    while((SYSCTL_PRGPIO_R&0x00000020)==0){}

    GPIO_PORTF_LOCK_R =0x4C4F434B ;    // Lock register .
    GPIO_PORTF_CR_R   =0XFF ;         // Commit register .
    GPIO_PORTF_DIR_R  =0x0E ;          // PF0 and PF4 input To control SW1,SW2.
    GPIO_PORTF_DEN_R  =0xFF ;          // Enabling all pins 
    GPIO_PORTF_PUE_R  =0X11 ;          
    }
```

Hi,

I am trying to do a sleeping led project on my tiva c card and I addressed the pins correctly but I get an error only in the part above. The error says "expected expression". Do you have an idea why am I getting this error?

Thanks.

I have checked the addresses and syntax error but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Compiler diagnostics provide more information than you have provided - specifically they specify the file and line number location of the error.  It would help a great deal if you provide _all_ the diagnostic information.  It is usually best and simplest to simply copy and paste the diagnostic verbatim rather than paraphrasing and eliding it.

Comment: More context required also.  Often an error at a specific line is the result of whatever _preceded_ it (directly on in a header file).  There is no obvious error in the code provided - the issue is in what you have not shown.